# Android AudioRecord is there a way to release when I no longer have a reference?

Tags: android, audiorecord

I'm implementing an Android app that uses microphone input via the AudioRecord class. I haven't called release() method on AudioRecord instance and closed the app. Now I'm not able to initialize another AudioRecord and recording audio is basically blocked for all other apps as well.

```
AudioHardwareALSA: error:Input stream already opened for voice recording
```

Is there any way to release AudioRecord instance when I no longer have a reference to it? The only way I've found so far is to restart a phone which is not a viable solution.

Comment: If losing reference is part of the design then you need to redesign. If the app encounters an exception and closes without calling `release()` then you need to catch any possible exceptions and call `release` then. This solution should only be used during development/debugging process and shouldn't be released as part of the final product.
In all other cases you will just have to reset the phone.

Comment: Loosing reference is not a part of design, but it may happen unintended (crash, exception, someone takes out battery from phone, etc...). Some devs. might not implement a proper release solution and therefor block recording audio in the whole system. That makes me feel a bit uncomfortable with the Android's AudioRecrod implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release all your resounrces in onDestroy Method

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // release resources
    releaseResources();
    visualizerView = null;
}
```

in release resources method what i do is see if recording is running then stop/ cancel it and thats all within try catch block

Comment: What if some other app will not release AudioRecord properly?

Comment: you mean you're using intent and showing another app to record audio? or is it in your own app?

Comment: I was wondering about a case when some other app not related to mine will not release AudioRecord properly. Than audio recording is blocked in the entire system and there is no way to overcome it other than restarting phone.